# Having trouble Loading a multilevel JSON file into Apache Pig and saving it as csv

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I'm super new to apache pig and was trying to load a multilevel json into pig and save it as csv.

Json file I have - home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a1321d5741a2384e802c552"},"reviewerID":"A3HVRXV0LVJN7","asin":"0110400550","reviewerName":"BiancaNicole","helpful":[4,4],"reviewText":"Best phone case ever . Everywhere I go I get a ton of compliments on it. It was in perfect condition as well.","overall":5.0,"summary":"A++++","unixReviewTime":1358035200,"reviewTime":"01 13, 2013","category":"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories","class":1.0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a1321d5741a2384e802c557"},"reviewerID":"A1BJGDS0L1IO6I","asin":"0110400550","reviewerName":"cf \"t\"","helpful":[0,3],"reviewText":"ITEM NOT SENT from Blue Top Company in Hong Kong and it's been over two months!  I will report this.  DO NOT use this company.  Not happy at all!","overall":1.0,"summary":"ITEM NOT SENT!!","unixReviewTime":1359504000,"reviewTime":"01 30, 2013","category":"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories","class":0.0}
```

Opened pig from the the directory(incase that is of any concern) - /home/vikaspattathe/dataset/

I tried the below commands to load the data and getting following errors.

```
grunt> sample_table = LOAD '/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json' USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, reviewerId:chararray, asin:chararray, reviewerName:chararray, reviewText:chararray, overall:int, summary:chararray, unixReviewTime:chararray, reviewTime:chararray, category:chararray, class:int');

2022-10-29 11:35:55,333 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryMan ager - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
2022-10-29 11:35:55,556 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-29 11:35:55,572 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-29 11:35:55,632 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
```

Tried dumping sample_table as I believe the load wasn't successfull.

```
grunt> dump sample_table;
2022-10-29 11:42:24,535 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-29 11:42:24,546 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2022-10-29 11:42:24,558 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-29 11:42:24,558 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2022-10-29 11:42:24,558 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, FilterConstantCalculator, ForEachConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitConstantCalculator, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2022-10-29 11:42:24,559 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2022-10-29 11:42:24,560 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2022-10-29 11:42:24,561 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2022-10-29 11:42:24,569 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-29 11:42:24,571 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:8032
2022-10-29 11:42:24,572 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy - Connecting to Application History server at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:10200
2022-10-29 11:42:24,575 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2022-10-29 11:42:24,575 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2022-10-29 11:42:24,576 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2022-10-29 11:42:24,621 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.18.0-SNAPSHOT-core-h3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp-403584597/pig-0.18.0-SNAPSHOT-core-h3.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,642 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp-332868819/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,663 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp759836349/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,683 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp-305484567/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,815 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-3.1.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp-1240067490/hive-exec-3.1.2.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/lib/pig/lib/RoaringBitmap-shaded-0.7.45.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp500810153/tmp-1911465994/RoaringBitmap-shaded-0.7.45.jar
2022-10-29 11:42:24,855 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2022-10-29 11:42:24,873 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2022-10-29 11:42:24,885 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:8032
2022-10-29 11:42:24,886 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy - Connecting to Application History server at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:10200
2022-10-29 11:42:24,906 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/vikaspattathe/.staging/job_1667038087507_0005
2022-10-29 11:42:24,908 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2022-10-29 11:42:24,960 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/vikaspattathe/.staging/job_1667038087507_0005
2022-10-29 11:42:24,963 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://spam-ham-m/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1565)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1562)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:298)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://spam-ham-m/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocatedFileStatusFetcher.getFileStatuses(LocatedFileStatusFetcher.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:396)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:283)
        ... 18 more
2022-10-29 11:42:25,375 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1667038087507_0005
2022-10-29 11:42:25,375 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases sample_table
2022-10-29 11:42:25,375 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: sample_table[1,15] C:  R: 
2022-10-29 11:42:25,384 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2022-10-29 11:42:30,393 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2022-10-29 11:42:30,393 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1667038087507_0005 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2022-10-29 11:42:30,393 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2022-10-29 11:42:30,395 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:8032
2022-10-29 11:42:30,396 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy - Connecting to Application History server at spam-ham-m/10.154.0.5:10200
2022-10-29 11:42:30,404 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1667038087507_0005. Redirecting to job history server.
2022-10-29 11:42:30,420 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
2022-10-29 11:42:30,421 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2022-10-29 11:42:30,421 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
3.2.3   0.18.0-SNAPSHOT vikaspattathe   2022-10-29 11:42:24     2022-10-29 11:42:30     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1667038087507_0005  sample_table    MAP_ONLY        Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://spam-ham-m/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1565)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1562)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:298)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://spam-ham-m/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocatedFileStatusFetcher.getFileStatuses(LocatedFileStatusFetcher.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:396)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:283)
        ... 18 more
        hdfs://spam-ham-m/tmp/temp500810153/tmp929245825,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://spam-ham-m/tmp/temp500810153/tmp929245825"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1667038087507_0005


2022-10-29 11:42:30,421 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2022-10-29 11:42:30,427 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias sample_table. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
Details at logfile: /home/vikaspattathe/dataset/pig_1667043341193.log
```

The load wasn't successful.

Also, is the below command correct for storing the file as samplecsv.csv, once it's successfuly loaded.

```
grunt> STORE sample_table INTO '/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/samplecsv' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

HDFS doesn't have `/home` file paths. User data is stored under `/user` paths. As the error says, the input you gave doesn't exist *in HDFS*.

If you want to load local filesystem, then prefix the path with `file://`

You also don't need HDFS to use pig, if you start it with `pig -x local`

As for the output, start with

```
X = LOAD '/tmp/sample.json' USING JsonLoader('id:(oid:chararray), reviewerID:chararray, asin:chararray, reviewerName:chararray, helpful:tuple(int), reviewText:chararray, overall:int, summary:chararray, unixReviewTime:long, reviewTime:chararray, category:chararray, class:int');
```

But I don't know how `helpful` field should be added for arrays... I tried `helpful:[int]`, and that produces the same result.

```
\DUMP X;
((5a1321d5741a2384e802c552),A3HVRXV0LVJN7,0110400550,BiancaNicole,,4,,,,,,)
((5a1321d5741a2384e802c557),A1BJGDS0L1IO6I,0110400550,cf "t",,3,,,,,,)
```

Comment: Thankyou. So would opening it in pig -x local work?
I opened pig in local and executed the above commands, but instead of creating a samplecsv.csv file, it created a directory samplecsv, and inside it a file called part-m-0000 containing comma seperated values(not a file of .csv) as below. This isn't the data I expected.

{,5a1321d5741a2384e802c552,reviewerID,asin,reviewerName,,,,,,
{,5a1321d5741a2384e802c557,reviewerID,asin,reviewerName,,,,,,
{,5a1321d5741a2384e802c550,reviewerID,asin,reviewerName,,,,,,

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong while loading. I used the code in the post

Comment: That's correct. Pig creates directories, not single files. Also see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_pigstore.htm

Comment: Okay, thank you. 
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong for the json I have with the below command. As it's not loading properly. I have posted the result I got in the last comment.                                                           

~~~ 
sample_table = LOAD '/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json' USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, reviewerId:chararray, asin:chararray, reviewerName:chararray, reviewText:chararray, overall:int, summary:chararray, unixReviewTime:chararray, reviewTime:chararray, category:chararray, class:int');
~~~

Comment: You don't have any field called id (the underscore matters, and it's not a chararray), and several fields should be float, not chararray or int

Comment: Btw, the schema is optional https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#jsonloadstore

Comment: I tried -> sample_table = LOAD '/home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json' USING JsonLoader();
But getting, ERROR 1131: Could not find schema file for /home/vikaspattathe/dataset/sample.json. It seems the .pig_schema wasn't automatically produced by JsonStorage.

Comment: I had missed the part of the docs that day .pig_schema file needs to be defined

Comment: @VikasPalakkat Updated answer with parser that gets some of the values correctly

Comment: Still, we're not able to load a lot of fields other than helpful - reviewText,overall,summary,etc.

Comment: I haven't used Pig with JSON before, and the docs aren't really clear how to handle arrays since tuples or bags need defined fields themselves